# remove and rebinding li tags to ul is not working

Tags: jquery

I am trying to rebind the li tags by removing it and again rebinding it. The ul tag is generated dynamically. My code to remove the li tags is this...

```
$("#ulActivity li").remove();
```

this line is removing all li tags perfectly, but append new set of li is not working...

```
$.each(objTaskActivityList, function(i,v){                    
     $("#ulActivity ul").append('<li><a onclick="javascript:openfile(\''+v.DOCName+'\')">'+v.DOCName+'</a></li>');
});
```

where i am doing mistake..

Comment: Maybe a problem with quotation marks. Have a look at the resulting DOM elements! You can easily avoid this by just using jQuery to bind the event handler. What are the values of `v.DOCName`?

Comment: Are you sure that the variables `i` and `v` from the `objTaskActivityList` object are what you expect?

Comment: ` $("#ulActivity ul")` you're sure you don't mean ` $("#ulActivity")`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should do

```
   $.each(objTaskActivityList, function(i,v){                    
       $("#ulActivity").append('<li><a onclick="javascript:openfile(\''+v.DOCName+'\')">'+v.DOCName+'</a></li>');
   });
```

$("#ulActivity ul") targets an `<ul>` that is a descendant of the element with id= ulActivity, which i think is your `<ul>`

In any case you should try to handle situations like these with an approach that is different from "Remove" and "Reattach", but how to that exactly depends from your needs

Comment: @user1295132 glad it helped, the next time you should post also your html (or at least the part that it's relevant to the question)

Comment: @user1295132 well if you need to remove the old elements and put in the new one, your code would be ok :)